# Regex validation for "no spaces"

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js

I have tried:

```
self.username = ko.observable(data.username || null)
    .extend({ required: true, maxLength: 50 })
    .extend({ pattern: { message: 'Username cannot contain spaces.', params: '^\S*$' } });
```

and

```
self.username = ko.observable(data.username || null)
    .extend({ required: true, maxLength: 50 })
    .extend({ pattern: { message: 'Username cannot contain spaces.', params: '[\S]' } });
```

but the validation error is flagged even with the value of "a".

The expression `'^\S*$'` seems to work on on-line JavaScript regex testers.
I am not sure why its flagging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a string to define the regular expression, you need to escape any backslashes, so it should be:

```
self.username = ko.observable(data.username || null)
   .extend({ required: true, maxLength: 50 })
   .extend({ pattern: { message: 'Username cannot contain spaces.', params: '^\\S*$' } });
```

If you use a regular expression literal instead of a string, you don't need to escape the backslash:

```
self.username = ko.observable(data.username || null)
   .extend({ required: true, maxLength: 50 })
   .extend({ pattern: { message: 'Username cannot contain spaces.', params: /^\S*$/ } });
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using ko.validation?

If fixing the regex does not work you can try something like this (untested)...

```
ko.validation.rules['doesntContain'] = {
    validator: function (val, checkFor) {
        return val.indexOf(checkFor) === -1;
    },
    message: 'The field must not contain [{0}]'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();


var myCustomObj = ko.observable(data.username || null).extend({ doesntContain: " " });
```

Comment: Why would I want to do this instead of just fixing the regexp? What's the problem with the regexp?

Comment: There is no problem with regex.  This was just another option in case you wanted to extend it to more characters.